# Graspit ROS - interface plugin

Tags: ros, plugin, grasping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed Graspit! for Diamondback from apt and it works fine. Now i would like to use the provided graspit_interface plugin. According to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/1418/grasping-force-closure-node) post, there should be a graspit_interface node for starting the simulator with a containing ROS node but in my install the package only compiles a shared library libros_graspit_interface.so. Could somebody with some experience with this tool maybe elaborate a bit on how to start/use the plugin or maybe provide some lines of code illustrating how to interact with it from within a ROS node?

Thanks,
-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12752/graspit-ros---interface-plugin/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fact, above question was addressed in the comments of the answer to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/1860/visualizing-3d-objects-from) post. When installing Graspit from debs, no launch file for the ROS interface is included opposed to an install from [source](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/graspit_simulator/) which provides a file   graspit_simulator/trunk/graspit_interface/launch/ros_graspit_interface.launch. Alternatively the node can also be started via 'rosrun graspit graspit plugin:libros_graspit_interface' (assuming $GRASPIT_PLUGIN_DIR is set to the directory containing the library libros_graspit_interface.so).

---

Originally posted by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) with karma: 225 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0